# While running oracle DBD::Oacle installation am getting this "Cannot find or open file: /lib32/crt0_64.o"

Tags: oracle, aix

While installing DBD::Oracle in AIX , I am getting the following error. The oracle client version is 11.2 
, I am not sure where I would missed this.

```
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::Oracle ()
        chmod 644 Oracle.bs
        rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
        LD_RUN_PATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib32:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2/rdbms/lib32" ld  -bhalt:4 -G -bI:/usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.10.1/aix-thread-multi/CORE/perl.exp -bE:Oracle.exp -bnoentry -lpthreads -lc -lm -L/usr/local/lib Oracle.o  dbdimp.o  oci8.o /lib32/crt0_64.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so           -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib32/ -lclntsh -lld -lm -ldl -lc -lm -lpthreads -lodm -lbsd_r -lld -lperfstat -lm -lpthreads
ld: 0706-005 Cannot find or open file: /lib32/crt0_64.o
        ld:open(): No such file or directory
make: The error code from the last command is 255.
```

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Aix.pod may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue because of perl compiler , the oracle version is 64 bit and the perl version is 32 bit. When I ran Makefile, It is compiling with perl 32 bit version and not able to find some of the library files.

So before making "MakeFile", ensure your oracle and perl version is the same bit. If it is not, please install or create soft link for perl 64 bit compiler.